# Linear regression, what happens to new betas when they're multiplied by a scalar

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Suppose that:
Y = 1 + 5X + ϵ
We multiply Y by 3 and X by 1/4 and compute a new regression model: find the values of β0, and β1.

Hi guys, I'm trying to solve this question my thinking leads me to solve the normal equation and calculate the new coefficents but i think my answer is wrong (with this it should be β0 = 1/3 and β1 = 5/12). Is there anyone that could help me and maybe explain me why I'm wrong? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If
$$Y = 1 + 5X + \epsilon$$
and
$$Y' = 3Y$$
$$X' = 1/4 X$$
then
$$Y'/3 = 1 + 5(4X') + \epsilon$$
so
$$Y' = 3 + 60X' + 3\epsilon$$